# Use na.rm=TRUE with functions inside mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to calculate cumulative sums and am using `mutate` to create the new column.  I am doing this for multiple columns and each has missing data in different places.

```
day    water    nitrogen
 1      4        5
 2      NA       6
 3      3        NA
 4      7        NA
 5      2        9
 6      NA       3
 7      2        NA
 8      NA       2
 9      7        NA
10      4        3
```

I try

```
mutate(df, sumwater = cumsum(water))%>%
mutate(sumnitrogen = cumsum(nitrogen))
```

or

```
mutate(df, sumwater = cumsum(water, na.rm = TRUE))%>%
mutate(sumnitrogen = cumsum(nitrogen, na.rm = TRUE))
```

neither works.  I know we can do `na.rm=TRUE` in `summarize` functions.  Is there a way to get it to work in `mutate`? I prefer a `dplyr` answer because in reality this part of a long chain of piping.

Comment: While not dplyr specific, good answers abut `cumsum` and `NA` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25576358/calculate-cumsum-while-ignoring-na-values)

Comment: `cumsum` has no `na.rm` argument, which isn't an issue specific to dplyr. See `?cumsum` for its docs.

Comment: You could also do something like `df %>% mutate(sumwater = cumsum(replace(water, is.na(water), 0)), sumnitrogen = cumsum(replace(nitrogen, is.na(nitrogen), 0)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution, that avoids loading `plyr`, is to instead use `tidyr::replace_na` (see http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/replace_na.html):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% replace_na(list(water = 0)) %>% mutate(sumwater = cumsum(water))
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to choose a replacement value for NA. You could do zero. But if these are true NA's, mean replacement seems to make more sense (or even geometric mean, if values are strictly greater than 0)

```
detach("package:dplyr")
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

mutate(df, sumwater = water %>% mapvalues(NA, 0) %>% cumsum)

mutate(df, sumwater = water %>% mapvalues(NA, mean(water) ) %>% cumsum)
```

Comment: You've got plyr down twice.

Comment: oops fixed. have to make sure to load plyr before dplyr