# Cummean ignoring NAs and replacing NA with last valid value

Tags: r, dplyr, mean, na

Similar to this post [Calculate cummean() and cumsd() while ignoring NA values and filling NAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980317/calculate-cummean-and-cumsd-while-ignoring-na-values-and-filling-nas) but I would rather stick to `tidyverse`

My data:

```
structure(list(season = c("Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", 
"Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Spring", "Spring", 
"Spring", "Spring", "Spring", "Spring", "Spring", "Spring", "Spring"
), tmean = c(NA, 2, 3, 4, NA, NA, NA, 8, NA, 7, 8, 9, NA, NA, 
5, 3, 2, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))

season tmean
Winter    NA
Winter     2
Winter     3
Winter     4
Winter    NA
Winter    NA
Winter    NA
Winter     8
Winter    NA
Spring     7
Spring     8
Spring     9
Spring    NA
Spring    NA
Spring     5
Spring     3
Spring     2
Spring    NA
```

What I want:

```
season tmean cumtmean
Winter    NA       NA
Winter     2        2
Winter     3      2.5
Winter     4        3
Winter    NA        3
Winter    NA        3
Winter    NA        3
Winter     8     4.25
Winter    NA     4.25
Spring     7        7
Spring     8      7.5
Spring     9        8
Spring    NA        8
Spring    NA        8
Spring     5     7.25
Spring     3      6.4
Spring     2     5.66
Spring    NA     5.66
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replace` + `cummean` to compute the cumulative mean, and `fill` to fill NAs downward:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df |> 
  group_by(season) |> 
  mutate(cumtmean = replace(tmean, complete.cases(tmean), cummean(na.omit(tmean)))) |> 
  fill(cumtmean) |> 
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 18 × 3
#    season tmean cumtmean
#    <chr>  <dbl>    <dbl>
#  1 Winter    NA    NA   
#  2 Winter     2     2   
#  3 Winter     3     2.5 
#  4 Winter     4     3   
#  5 Winter    NA     3   
#  6 Winter    NA     3   
#  7 Winter    NA     3   
#  8 Winter     8     4.25
#  9 Winter    NA     4.25
# 10 Spring     7     7   
# 11 Spring     8     7.5 
# 12 Spring     9     8   
# 13 Spring    NA     8   
# 14 Spring    NA     8   
# 15 Spring     5     7.25
# 16 Spring     3     6.4 
# 17 Spring     2     5.67
# 18 Spring    NA     5.67
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own helper function to take into account the NA values.

```
cummean_na <- function(x) {
  num <- cumsum(tidyr::replace_na(x,0))
  denom <- cumsum(!is.na(x))
  if_else(denom!=0, num/denom, NA)
}
```

And then if your data.frame is called `dd` you can use `dplyr` to do

```
dd %>% 
  mutate(cmtean = cummean_na(tmean), .by=season)
```

which returns the expected values

```
   season tmean   cmtean
1  Winter    NA       NA
2  Winter     2 2.000000
3  Winter     3 2.500000
4  Winter     4 3.000000
5  Winter    NA 3.000000
6  Winter    NA 3.000000
7  Winter    NA 3.000000
8  Winter     8 4.250000
9  Winter    NA 4.250000
10 Spring     7 7.000000
11 Spring     8 7.500000
12 Spring     9 8.000000
13 Spring    NA 8.000000
14 Spring    NA 8.000000
15 Spring     5 7.250000
16 Spring     3 6.400000
17 Spring     2 5.666667
18 Spring    NA 5.666667
```

Answer (score 1):

In case *no additional package is even better than one*, I would like to add that [@MrFlick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77565037/20002111) can be easily translated to base R using `ave()`:

```
with(dd, ave(x = tmean, season, FUN = \(ii) { 
  y <- ii
  y[is.na(y)] <- 0L
  num <- cumsum(y)
  denom <- cumsum(!is.na(ii))
  ifelse(denom != 0L, num / denom, NA)})
  )
```