# R: ranking variable per trial according to time column

Tags: r, data.table

My data looks like this:

```
Subject  Trial  Task  Time  Fixation
..
1        1       2    1      0.335
1        1       2    456    NA
1        1       2    765    0.165
1        1       2    967    0.445
..
2        3       1    1      0.665
2        3       1    300    0.556
2        3       1    570    NA
2        3       1    900    NA
..
15       5       3    1      0.766
15       5       3    567    0.254
15       5       3    765    0.167
15       5       3    1465   NA
..
```

I want to create a column FixationID where I want to rank every Fixation **per Trial** according to Time column (1,2,3,4..). Time column shows time course in milliseconds for every trial and every Trial starts with 1. Trials have different lengths.

I want my data to look like this:

```
Subject  Trial  Task  Time  Fixation FixationID
..
1        1       2    1      0.335    1
1        1       2    456    NA       NA
1        1       2    765    0.165    2
1        1       2    967    0.445    3
..
2        3       1    1      0.665    1
2        3       1    300    0.556    2
2        3       1    570    NA       NA
2        3       1    900    NA       NA
..
15       5       3    1      0.766    1
15       5       3    567    0.254    2
15       5       3    765    0.167    3
15       5       3    1465   NA       NA
..
```

I tried

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)[!is.na(Fixation), FixID := 
              seq_len(.N)[order(Time)], by = Trial]
```

but what I get is ranking 1,16,31,45,57.. for my Subject 1 Trial 1. I want 1,2,3,4,5..

Can anyone help me with this?

Excerpt from my data:

```
structure(list(Subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Trial = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Task = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Time = c(1L, 385L, 571L, 638L, 951L, 
1020L, 1349L, 1401L, 1661L, 1706L, 2042L, 2067L, 2322L, 2375L, 
2540L, 2660L, 2686L, 3108L, 3172L, 3423L, 3462L, 3845L, 3870L, 
3969L, 4099L, 4132L, 1L, 471L, 513L, 697L), Fixation = c(0.383, 
0.185, NA, 0.312, NA, 0.328, NA, 0.259, NA, 0.335, NA, 0.254, 
NA, 0.164, 0.119, NA, 0.421, NA, 0.25, NA, 0.382, NA, 0.0979999999999999, 
0.129, NA, 0.335, 0.469, NA, 0.183, NA)), .Names = c("Subject", 
"Trial", "Task", "Time", "Fixation"), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Nice clear presentation of the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ave` on `as.logical(Fixation)` and *@josliber*'s [`NA`-ignoring `cumsum` code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25576972/6574038).

```
mydata$FixationID <- 
  with(mydata, ave(as.logical(Fixation), Subject, Trial, FUN=function(x) 
    cumsum(ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x)) + x*0))
```

#### Result

```
mydata
#    Subject Trial task Time Fixation FixationID
# 1        1     1    1    1    0.596          1
# 10       1     1    1  500    0.016          2
# 19       1     1    1  512       NA         NA
# 28       1     1    1  524       NA         NA
# 4        1     2    2    1    0.688          1
# 13       1     2    2  501       NA         NA
# 22       1     2    2  513       NA         NA
# 31       1     2    2  525       NA         NA
# 7        1     3    3    1    0.582          1
# 16       1     3    3  502       NA         NA
# 25       1     3    3  514    0.369          2
# 34       1     3    3  526    0.847          3
# 2        2     1    1    1       NA         NA
# 11       2     1    1  503    0.779          1
# 20       2     1    1  515    0.950          2
# 29       2     1    1  527    0.304          3
# 5        2     2    2    1    0.158          1
# 14       2     2    2  504    0.281          2
# 23       2     2    2  516    0.360          3
# 32       2     2    2  528    0.535          4
# 8        2     3    3    1       NA         NA
# 17       2     3    3  505    0.717          1
# 26       2     3    3  517       NA         NA
# 35       2     3    3  529    0.959          2
# 3        3     1    1    1    0.174          1
# 12       3     1    1  506    0.278          2
# 21       3     1    1  518    0.784          3
# 30       3     1    1  530       NA         NA
# 6        3     2    2    1    0.439          1
# 15       3     2    2  507    0.857          2
# 24       3     2    2  519       NA         NA
# 33       3     2    2  531    0.019          3
# 9        3     3    3    1    0.175          1
# 18       3     3    3  508    0.314          2
# 27       3     3    3  520       NA         NA
# 36       3     3    3  532    0.845          3
```

---

*Data*

```
mydata <- structure(list(Subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Trial = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), task = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3
), Time = c(1, 500, 512, 524, 1, 501, 513, 525, 1, 502, 514, 
526, 1, 503, 515, 527, 1, 504, 516, 528, 1, 505, 517, 529, 1, 
506, 518, 530, 1, 507, 519, 531, 1, 508, 520, 532), Fixation = c(0.596, 
0.016, NA, NA, 0.688, NA, NA, NA, 0.582, NA, 0.369, 0.847, NA, 
0.779, 0.95, 0.304, 0.158, 0.281, 0.36, 0.535, NA, 0.717, NA, 
0.959, 0.174, 0.278, 0.784, NA, 0.439, 0.857, NA, 0.019, 0.175, 
0.314, NA, 0.845)), row.names = c(1L, 10L, 19L, 28L, 4L, 13L, 
22L, 31L, 7L, 16L, 25L, 34L, 2L, 11L, 20L, 29L, 5L, 14L, 23L, 
32L, 8L, 17L, 26L, 35L, 3L, 12L, 21L, 30L, 6L, 15L, 24L, 33L, 
9L, 18L, 27L, 36L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)
mydata[!is.na(Fixation), FixID := frank(Time), by = Trial]

head(mydata, 10)
    Subject Trial Task Time Fixation FixID
 1:       1     1    2    1    0.383     1
 2:       1     1    2  385    0.185     2
 3:       1     1    2  571       NA    NA
 4:       1     1    2  638    0.312     3
 5:       1     1    2  951       NA    NA
 6:       1     1    2 1020    0.328     4
 7:       1     1    2 1349       NA    NA
 8:       1     1    2 1401    0.259     5
 9:       1     1    2 1661       NA    NA
10:       1     1    2 1706    0.335     6

tail(mydata, 10)
    Subject Trial Task Time Fixation FixID
 1:       1     1    2 3462    0.382    12
 2:       1     1    2 3845       NA    NA
 3:       1     1    2 3870    0.098    13
 4:       1     1    2 3969    0.129    14
 5:       1     1    2 4099       NA    NA
 6:       1     1    2 4132    0.335    15
 7:       1     2    2    1    0.469     1
 8:       1     2    2  471       NA    NA
 9:       1     2    2  513    0.183     2
10:       1     2    2  697       NA    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option which should be fast:

```
setDT(mydata)[!is.na(Fixation), FixID := .SD[order(Trial, Time), rowid(Trial)]]
mydata
```