# Create runs of repeating values in a character vector with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is the data:

```
df0 <-
  data.frame(id = 1:13,
             type = c("not_applicable",
                      "new",
                      "same",
                      "same",
                      "not_applicable",
                      "new",
                      "new",
                      "new",
                      "same",
                      "same",
                      "not_applicable",
                      "new",
                      "same"))
```

I would like to assign indexes to runs that start with "new", and zeroes to "not_applicable" values, using `dplyr`. Each "new" value gets the next index (1, 2, 3, etc.), and each "same" value gets the same index as the previous "new." Runs always start with "new," followed by "same" if there are >1 values.

Desired output:

```
data.frame(id = 1:13,
             type = c("not_applicable",
                      "new",
                      "same",
                      "same",
                      "not_applicable",
                      "new",
                      "new",
                      "new",
                      "same",
                      "same",
                      "not_applicable",
                      "new",
                      "same"),
             index = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 0, 5, 5))
```

I tried this:

```
df0 %>% 
  mutate(index = with(rle(type != "not_applicable"),
                      rep(cumsum(values) * values, lengths)))
```

But it's giving me the following output:

```
   id           type index
1   1 not_applicable     0
2   2            new     1
3   3           same     1
4   4           same     1
5   5 not_applicable     0
6   6            new     2
7   7            new     2
8   8            new     2
9   9           same     2
10 10           same     2
11 11 not_applicable     0
12 12            new     3
13 13           same     3
```

I'd like to assign the next index to each sequence that starts with "new."

Comment: If your "not_applicable" value can be set to `NA`, the constant for missing value, then check out answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25576358/calculate-cumsum-while-ignoring-na-values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may take help of `cumsum` -

```
library(dplyr)

df0 %>%
  mutate(index = cumsum(type == "new"), 
         index = replace(index, type == "not_applicable", 0))

#   id           type index
#1   1 not_applicable     0
#2   2            new     1
#3   3           same     1
#4   4           same     1
#5   5 not_applicable     0
#6   6            new     2
#7   7            new     3
#8   8            new     4
#9   9           same     4
#10 10           same     4
#11 11 not_applicable     0
#12 12            new     5
#13 13           same     5
```

Answer (score 4):

base R:

```
df0$index <- cumsum(df0$type == 'new') * (df0$type != 'not_applicable')
```

Or

---

```
transform(df0, index = cumsum(type == 'new')* (type != 'not_applicable'))

   id           type index
1   1 not_applicable     0
2   2            new     1
3   3           same     1
4   4           same     1
5   5 not_applicable     0
6   6            new     2
7   7            new     3
8   8            new     4
9   9           same     4
10 10           same     4
11 11 not_applicable     0
12 12            new     5
13 13           same     5
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a combination of `lead()` and `lag()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(index = lag(cumsum(ifelse(lead(type)  == "new", 1, 0))),
         index = ifelse(type == "not_applicable", 0, index))

   id           type tile_x
1   1 not_applicable      0
2   2            new      1
3   3           same      1
4   4           same      1
5   5 not_applicable      0
6   6            new      2
7   7            new      3
8   8            new      4
9   9           same      4
10 10           same      4
11 11 not_applicable      0
12 12            new      5
13 13           same      5
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `purrr::accumulate()`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df0 %>%
  mutate(
    index = accumulate(
      type, 
      \(x, y) if_else(y == "new", x + 1, x),
     .init = 0
    )[-1],
    index = if_else(type == "not_applicable", 0, index)
)
```

Or with `Reduce()` in base R:

```r
df0$index <- ifelse(
  df0$type == "not_applicable",
  0,
  Reduce(
    \(x, y) ifelse(y == "new", x + 1, x), 
    df0$type, 
    accumulate = TRUE, 
    init = 0
  )[-1]
)
```

Result:

```
   id           type index
1   1 not_applicable     0
2   2            new     1
3   3           same     1
4   4           same     1
5   5 not_applicable     0
6   6            new     2
7   7            new     3
8   8            new     4
9   9           same     4
10 10           same     4
11 11 not_applicable     0
12 12            new     5
13 13           same     5
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new column `runner` that identifies `type == new`
2. Run a `cumsum` on it
3. apply your condition with `ifelse` within the column
4. remove the helper columns

```
library(dplyr)

df0 %>%
  mutate(runner = type == "new",
         run_x = cumsum(runner)) %>% 
  mutate(index = ifelse(type == "not_applicable", 0, run_x), .by=run_x) %>% 
  select(-c(runner, run_x))
```

```
  id           type index
1   1 not_applicable     0
2   2            new     1
3   3           same     1
4   4           same     1
5   5 not_applicable     0
6   6            new     2
7   7            new     3
8   8            new     4
9   9           same     4
10 10           same     4
11 11 not_applicable     0
12 12            new     5
13 13           same     5
```